# How do I get an address of an array inside a struct?

Tags: c++

I’m trying to get a pointer to an array that’s in a struct, but doing `*(struct->array)` gives me an error.

Here’s the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Numbers {
    int highest;
    int lowest;
    int list[10]; 
};

void print_pointer_to_first_number(const Numbers* num) {
     cout << num.list << endl;
}

int main() {
    Numbers numbers; 
    numbers.highest = 10;
    numbers.lowest = 1;

    print_pointer_to_first_number(numbers);

    return 1;
}
```

I’m getting an error saying:

> error: member reference type 'const Numbers *' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?

I am not allowed to change the argument in the function.

Comment: Not to mention that you never allocated any memory for the pointers at `int* list[10];`. Don't bother with such stuff in c++, but use the appropriate containers.

Comment: Are you working from a book or a tutorial?

Comment: *did you mean to use '->'?* Yes you did. `num.list` should be `num->list`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to pass Numbers as reference rather than a pointer (essentially the same, but with nicer syntax):

```
void print_pointer_to_first_number(const Numbers &num)
```

Alternatively you can keep it as a pointer, but then you'll need to (1) dereference it properly:

```
num->list
```

and (2) pass a pointer when you call it:

```
print_pointer_to_first_number(&numbers)
```